# ROS import srv message - relative import jump issue

Tags: python, ros

I am currently having some issue importing .srv files i've defined somewhere which i can't import into my service_def.py file.. Why is that not possible?

I made it as a rosnode, my src folder of the catkin_workspace looks like this

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
└── service
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── service
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── service_def.py
    │       └── service_def.pyc
    ├── package.xml
    ├── setup.py
    ├── src
    │   └── service_node.py
    └── srv
        ├── get.srv
        ├── set.srv
        └── __init__.py
```

service_def.py is defined as such

```
from ..srv import *
```

And my service_node.py which i `rosrun` imports service_def.py

```
import service.service_def
```

So why cant I import my service messages in service_def.py?

error message:

```
k@k:~/python_service/src$ rosrun service service_node.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/k/python_service/src/service/src/service_node.py", line 5, in <module>
    import service.service_def
  File "/home/k/python_service/src/service/include/service/service_def.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..srv import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

My setup.py looks like this:

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup
# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
packages=['service'],
package_dir={'': 'include'},
)
setup(**setup_args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you are trying to do a relative import (i.e. using `..`). Instead, since you are already setting `service` as a package in your `setup.py` file you can used that package name directly by changing:

`from ..srv import *`  in `service_def.py` to  `from service.service_def import *`.

Comment: how does it import the service files?

Comment: The issue is in the import of `service_def.py`.. It doesn't import the srv files.

Comment: @CarltonBanks This is assuming your `setup.py` defines service (which according to the Traceback it does) and that in `CMakeLists.txt` you have defined the service files (as specified in the ROS tutorials) . You can take a look at this [tutorial] (http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile) to see an example of how `setup.py` is used by catkin.

Comment: @CarltonBanks yes, inside the `service_def.py` you should change how you import the services.

Comment: @CarltonBanks My apologies, you're correct it doesn't import the files. Please see this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/248646/include-srv-files-in-python-catkin-project/?answer=248689#post-id-248689) with a MWE.